# What does tagging a note with a page in Facebook do?

Tags: facebook

In a Facebook note, you can tag a person or a page.

If you tag a person, it seems to appear as a notification to that person,
as well as to their friends.

If you tag a page, it's really not clear how it relates to that object.

I recently tagged a page that I am the owner of, and I saw no result.

Can anybody explain what page tagging does or is for?

Answer (score 4):

It notifies the other person that you've written about them should they have a Facebook account.  It also ties them to what you've written about when other people click their name in the notes.

Comment: I guess I thought there was some sort of track-back from pages to notes about them.  But that isn't the case.